# Using UNIQUE with non-adjecent columns on different sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have two tables on two sheets - let's say tblFruits1 and tblFruits2.
Both have a column "Name".
Apple - for example - exists on both lists.
The lists might have a different number of rows

*tblFruits1 on Sheet1*

| Name | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | red |
| Peach | yellow |
| Ananas | yellow |

*tblFruits2 on Sheet2*

| Name | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | red |
| Cherries | red |
| Banana | yellow |
| Melone | green |

Now I would like to get - on a third sheet - a UNIQUE list of names of both tables.

**expected result on Sheet3**

| Name |
| --- |
| Apple |
| Peach |
| Ananas |
| Cherries |
| Banana |
| Melone |

`=UNION((tblFruits1[Name],tblFruits2[Name]))` returns an error.

I tried variants with `SEQUENCE` and `INDEX` but didn't succeed.

So the question is:

**How can I "construct" the matrix-parameter for UNIQUE from two column-ranges on two different sheets?**

(What I am looking for is a **non-VBA**-solution - I know how to handle this in VBA.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `VSTACK` function makes the Union obsolete (only available to insiders at time of writing)

Since finding the Union of several ranges is a quite usefull function on its own, I use a LAMBDA to do that.  The output of that can then be passed to UNIQUE

The Lambda, which I call, unimaginatively, UNION

```
=LAMBDA(tabl1, tabl2,
        LET(rowindex, SEQUENCE(ROWS(tabl1)+ROWS(tabl2)),
            colindex, SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(tabl1)),
            IF(rowindex<=ROWS(tabl1), 
               INDEX(tabl1,rowindex,colindex),  
               INDEX(tabl2,rowindex-ROWS(tabl1),colindex)
            )
        )
 )
```

Then

```
=UNIQUE(Union(tblFruits1[Name],tblFruits2[Name]))
```

gives the result you seek

[image]

Comment: This is great!!! And supports me to prepare a question about best practice regarding the use of  LAMDA and LET (Although I don't yet have LAMBDA)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
=LET(X,CHOOSE({1,2},tblFruits1[Name],tblFruits2[Name]),Y,COUNTA(X),Z,MOD(SEQUENCE(Y)-1,Y/2)+1,A,INDEX(X,Z,CEILING(SEQUENCE(Y)/(Y/2),1)),UNIQUE(FILTER(A,NOT(ISNA(A)))))
```

[image]

Comment: I am deepy impressed - thanks. What I did to understand the formula: I pasted each element (X, Y, Z) as a single formula to the sheet to see the result. By that it is possible to understand the logic behind the formula. But I have no idea how I could build that on my own. Could you suggest tutorials or anything else to become more experienced in using the new opportunities?

Comment: Good to know it works! It's rather hard to explain these formulas sometimes so I don't always do so in detail. Good to see you managed yourself =) @Ike

Comment: What I did to understand is rename the variables and another split (your A has become columnMatrix and mergedColumn): `=LET(
mergedArray,CHOOSE({1,2},tblFruits1[Name],tblFruits2[Name]),
cntCells,COUNTA(mergedArray),
rowMatrix,MOD(SEQUENCE(cntCells)-1,cntCells/2)+1,
columnMatrix,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(cntCells)/(cntCells/2),0),
mergedColumn,INDEX(mergedArray,rowMatrix,columnMatrix),
UNIQUE(FILTER(mergedColumn,NOT(ISNA(mergedColumn)))))`

Comment: I have never done that before: but I will switch my accepted answer to the one of @chris neilsen. It looks less complicated - even if you don't use LAMBDA yet but put the UNIQUE around the LET-function

Answer (score 2):

Several answers already referred to the [`VSTACK`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vstack-function-a4b86897-be0f-48fc-adca-fcc10d795a9c) function to return the union of two tables or arrays, it's now available in several Excel versions. It can be combined with [`UNIQUE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e) (as already said too):

```
=UNIQUE(VSTACK(tblFruits1[Name];tblFruits2[Name]))
```

Here is the screenshot of the result (tried on Excel 365):

[image: Excel demo of UNIQUE and VSTACK]

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution I created where you can replace a2# and c2# with any two arrays, dynamic arrays, etc.  It also deduplicates and sorts it.  This works on Excel for Mac (FILTERXML is not supported)

```
=LET(
firstArray, a2#,
secondArray, c2#,
totalCount, COUNTA(firstArray)+COUNTA(secondArray),
firstCount, COUNTA(firstArray),
SORT(UNIQUE(MAKEARRAY(totalCount,1,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(r<=firstCount,INDEX(firstArray,r),INDEX(secondArray,r-firstCount+1))))))
)
```

Comment: `MAKEARRAY` is a cool function :-) making the solution - in my eyes - more understandable :-) But I had to remove the last `+1` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this and make your Sheet1 data and Sheet2 data into Table
an in your Sheet3 cell A2 copy paste the formula below

=UNIQUE(FILTERXML("**"&TEXTJOIN("****",1,(IFNA(IF({0,1},Table1[Name],Table2[Name]),"")))&"**","//b"),FALSE,FALSE)

Comment: I dont't get this running - I suppose it is somehow due to "//b". What does it mean as xPath? Word-boundaries? But where do they come from. Adjusting the formula to `=UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<x><y>" & TEXTJOIN("</y><y>",1,T(IFNA(IF({0,1},tblFruits1[Name],tblFruits2[Name]),""))) &"</y></x>","//y"),FALSE,FALSE)` worked.

Comment: @Ike `FILTERXML` has a limit on the string length it can handle of about 32000 characters (including all the xml stuff) If you have a large set of long(ish) strings, that could be exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new function that simplifies this: [VSTACK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vstack-function-a4b86897-be0f-48fc-adca-fcc10d795a9c)

For a unique (distinct) union (as per the original question), try this:

```
=UNIQUE((tblFruits1[Name],tblFruits2[Name]))
```

And to sort them:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE((tblFruits1[Name],tblFruits2[Name])))
```

Comment: Up to now I don't have VSTACK :-( - but where does it go in the formulas you show in your example?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. In my version of Excel UNIQUE does not accept 2 table column references (or table references) for the array argument as is proposed in this solution.  
using: Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2202 Build 16.0.14931.20602) 32-bit

Answer (score 0):

I don't have `VSTACK` or `HSTACK` at this point (or `LAMBDA` either), unless I resort to keeping workbooks on slow-and-clunky Excel Online.  But say you have 3 dynamic arrays (named **three**, **four** and **five**), each with 2 columns and a variable number of rows.  Then (to keep things readable) use a named formula **combo** defined as `=SEQUENCE(ROWS(three)+ROWS(four)+ROWS(five))`.  Then this works:

```
=IFS(
combo<=ROWS(three),              three,
combo<=ROWS(three)+ROWS(four),   INDEX(four,combo-ROWS(three),{1,2}),
TRUE,                            INDEX(five,combo-ROWS(three)-ROWS(four),{1,2})                                                     
    )
```

You can wrap `UNIQUE` and/or `SORT` around this, if you like.  If the arrays have 3 columns rather than 2 then use `{1,2,3}` in the formula.
Obviously you can expand this to more than 3 arrays by building more conditions into the `IFS` formula.

Perhaps it's worth noting that `three` is the same thing as `INDEX(three,combo,{1,2})`.  And using `COLUMN(three)` would make the syntax more generalisable, though it doesn't allow you to re-order the columns if you want something like `{2,1,3}` in your output.  Also, `TRUE` is effectively how you say "ELSE" in an `IFS` formula--it's a bit more concise here than `combo<=ROWS(three)+ROWS(four)+ROWS(five)`.  Using these longer forms would make the formula more symmetrical but a lot wordier!

(It would be nice if `VSTACK` ever becomes available on the desktop.)

Comment: In the meantime VSTACK is part of the current channel (desktop) - maybe you will get it with the semi-annual rollout. Your solution is more or less a rebuild of Chris Neilsens Lambda ...

Comment: Yeah, well we don't have LAMBDA yet either.