# Excel 365 Formulas - How to save LAMBDA function permanently (for all existing and new files)?

Tags: vba, lambda, excel-formula, microsoft365

I would like a global solution every time I start Excel365 with my key add-in also firing up.

I defined several LAMBDA custom functions, saved them in my add-in, and I would like to make them available globally - not just only for the current workbook. Is it possible? I tried saving a workbook with definition as an add-in (.xlam) but the formulas are not available.   The don't seem to be available when as an add-in.   When I am in the add-in parent file on the desktop, all is good and everything is running.  But once I post the file back for your as an add-in, The Lambda(s) and the defined name space go away.

Comment: AFAIK anything defined in the name manager (including LAMBDAs) are local to the workbook thet are defined in.  I think the closest you'll get currently to a globally available LAMDBA is to add a routine to your addin that adds the LAMBDAs to another workbook, either automatically or on demand.

Comment: I had the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69872165/16578424, @dbb provided a good answer

Comment: Thanks  I will use VBA as a Workaround.  I appreciate your knowledge.  I was hoping to use the LAMDAS alone and deliver it to a couple of my Mac and iPad friends.   I hope Microsoft builds this in in the future, for Microsoft its an opportunity.  I would check this as a yes, solved, if I could.  Thank you again!!

Comment: My additional work around is also simple.  If the LAMBDAs were saved in the original Workbook with "Workbook" as the saved parameter.  Then each of those worksheets in the original LAMBDA workbook is "infected" with all of the workbook LAMBDAs.  Therefore, I simply copy a blank worksheet from the original Workbook to the "new" workbook.  Then by virtue of "infection" the new workbook is also newly infected with all of the new LAMBDAs.   It works just like COVID, who knew?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try creating a template for excel to load when it is opened.

[Customizing how Excel starts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-how-excel-starts-6509b9af-2cc8-4fb6-9ef5-cf5f1d292c19) so it utilized the template.

Comment: This might help for new files.  It does nothing for existing files.

Answer (score 2):

My additional work around is also simple. If the LAMBDAs were saved in the original Workbook with "Workbook" as the saved parameter. Then each of those worksheets in the original LAMBDA workbook is "infected" with all of the workbook LAMBDAs. Therefore, I simply copy a blank worksheet from the original Workbook to the "new" workbook. Then by virtue of "infection" the new workbook is also newly infected with all of the new LAMBDAs. It works just like COVID, who knew?