# Better formula to calculate the union of 2 ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two ranges B4:B10 and C5:C10 as follows. I'm looking for a formula to calculate the union of the two ranges (so there will be no duplicates in the result).

[image]

At the moment, my formula is as follows. It applies `UNIQUE` to the concatenation of the 2 ranges. But I'm wondering if there is a better (eg, shorter) formula to do it.

```
= UNIQUE(LET(
           la,
           B5:B10,
           lb,
           C5:C10,
           i,
           SEQUENCE(ROWS(la) + ROWS(lb)),
           r,
           IF(i <= ROWS(la), la, INDEX(lb, i - ROWS(la))),
           r))
```

Could anyone help?

PS: I would prefer a solution without LAMBDA function and its helper functions.

Comment: I don't think it gets better than this by formula

Comment: Seems about right to me without `LAMBDA()`. The only other thing is `FILTERXML()` & `TEXTJOIN()`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62205206/9758194).

Comment: Nice different approach, but limited to Windows environment.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69837142/16578424

Answer (score 2):

The code I use for a 2D combined unique list is the following but it is calculation intensive with large data sets (and it is definitely not shorter), but it does work with any size of 2D data range:

```
=LET(array, Data,
     list, INDEX(array, ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(array)*COLUMNS(array))/COLUMNS(array),0), MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(array)*COLUMNS(array),,0), COLUMNS(array))+1),
     UNIQUE(FILTER(list, LEN(list)>0)))
```

> Where `Data` is a dynamic named range for me

---

However: having just researched the question a little; this is achievable via a pivot table; for the data area, you need to include a blank row above and blank column to the left where labels would be in a table

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1966-excel-extract-unique-values-from-multiple-columns.html

Comment: Thank you, I see your formula concatenate everything of a table and then does `UNIQUE`.