# Filter function for multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, filter, excel-formula

I am trying to filter data from multiple sheets using the newly introduced FILTER function. I have saved a named range for sheet names to use as an Array.
This is the formula I am trying to yse but it gives me #Value error. But it works if I use for a single sheet. aharu is the namedrange array for Sheet Names.

```
=FILTER(INDIRECT("'"&aharu&"'!$B$2:$B$1200"),(INDIRECT("'"&aharu&"'!$L$2:$L$1200")="")*(INDIRECT("'"&aharu&"'!$J$2:$J$1200")<=EDATE(TODAY(),-6)),"No data")
```

How to use filter function for multiple sheets?

Comment: FILTER function does not take multiple ranges regardless of wether they are on the same sheet or on multiple sheets. You would have to "simulate" a merged range and then Filter on that "range", look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69861437/16578424: it's the same question but with UNION instead of FILTER

Comment: If you create a resource worksheet with the required multiple ranges side by side, then the answer should be similar to the Q&A here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70616932/3688861

Answer (score -1):

To filter by using the `FILTER` function in Excel, follow these steps:

Type `=FILTER(` to begin your filter formula

Type the address for the range of cells that contains the data that you want to filter, such as `B1:C50`

Type a comma, and then type the condition for the filter, such as `C3:C50>3` (To set a condition, first type the address of the "criteria column" such as `B1:B`, then type an operator symbol such as greater than (`>`), and then type the criteria, such as the number `3`.

Type a closing parenthesis and then press enter on the keyboard. Your entire formula will look like this: `=FILTER(B1:C50,C1:C50>3)`

Here are the Excel Filters formulas:

1. Filter by a number

   ```
   =FILTER(A3:B12, B3:B12>0.7)
   ```
2. Filter by a cell value

   ```
   =FILTER(A3:B12, B3:B12<F1)
   ```
3. Filter by a text string

   ```
   =FILTER(A3:B12, B3:B12="Late")
   ```
4. Filter where NOT equal to

   ```
   =FILTER(A3:E1000, B3:B1000<>"Bob")
   ```
5. Filter by date

   ```
   =FILTER(A3:C12,C3:C12<G1)   (Date entered in cell G1)
   =FILTER(A3:C12,C3:C12<DATE(2019,6,1))
   ```
6. Filter by multiple conditions

   ```
   =FILTER(A3:C12,(B3:B12="Late")*(C3:C12="Active"))   (AND logic)
   =FILTER(A3:C12, (B3:B12="Late")+(C3:C12="Active"))   (OR logic)
   ```
7. Filter from another sheet

   ```
   =FILTER('Sheet Name'!A3:B12,'Sheet Name'!B3:B12="Full Time")
   ```
8. The Excel FILTER function:

   ```
   =FILTER(A3:B12, B3:B12=F1)
   ```

Comment: This will not work to filter data from multiple sheet at the same time which OP want.

Comment: I know how to use the FILTER function. I just need to know how to filter data from multiple sheets.

Comment: @Keto May be that is not possible in excel but can do in google-sheet.