# vba concatenate three (dynamic) tables into a master one

Tags: excel, vba

I am wanting to concatenate separate tables from separate excel worksheets to create one master one.The issue with the tables is that they are dynamic ie, one table could have 100 rows, the other one could have 240, third table could have 50 for example. The tables themselves were generated by quite a few different processes, essentially they had individual filters applied and then were copied and pasted into these separate excel worksheets… ready to be used to concatenated!

I’ve managed to do all of the processes in vba so could prefer to stick with it. I don’t want to use power query (Because of connection issues and also wanted this to be automated). I also don’t want to get involved with pivot tables or do this in the sql database. This is for quite a few different reasons… and so would prefer to stick to VBA.

```
Ie 
Table 1

Column a        column b    column c
Africa          100         4
Australia       0.1         5
America         200         7

Table 2
Column a        column b        column c
China           300         4
Australia       0.1         4
America        100          4


Table3
Column a        column b        column c
Bali            100         4
England         0.1         5
NZ              200         8


Result
Column a        column b        column c
Africa          100         4
Australia       0.1         5
America         200         7
China           300         4
Australia       0.1         4
America         100         4
Bali            100         4
England         0.1         5
NZ              200         8
```

If anyone has any recommendations, would love to hear

Comment: "I’ve managed to do all of the processes in vba"  - then surely you could at least have a stab at doing the concatenation?  If you run into problems then post your code with an explanation of what specifically happens/doesn't happen when you run it.

Comment: You can use the UNION Lambda from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69861437) (nested to Union 3 tables)