# Excel: combine 3 ranges from different sheets

Tags: excel

In Excel 365 I have data across three sheets, which I want to filter, sort and rearrange. I have a function that does this for the relevant array in the first sheet:

```
=SORT(FILTER(FILTER('Sheet1'!C10:F88, ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".",'Sheet1'!F10:F88))),{1,0,0,1}),2)
```

Now I also have two more arrays in two different sheets that I would like to add to this function, so that the result is one long array that contains the filtered and sorted data. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at vstack https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-new-text-and-array-functions/ba-p/3186066

Comment: or look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69837142/16578424