# Get Unique Range from Multiple Dynamic Named Ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two named ranges that are dynamic in length that I would like to combine into one range with just the unique values from the two. In other words, I essentially am hoping to get a union of the two ranges and then get the unique values. Below is a small toy example to demonstrate. I'm hoping to find a solution without using VBA, etc.

Two dynamic named ranges:

[image: First Named Range]

[image: Second Named Range]

And the desired result would be:

[image: Resultant Named Range]

Comment: You need `VSTACK()` function if your version of excel support it.

Comment: I don't think I have access to `VSTACK()` with Microsoft 365?

Comment: Can you please try my below answer then feedback.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69837142/16578424 - there are answers w/o FILTERXML

Comment: Your title says *multiple* Named Ranges but then you appear to require only two. Can you clarify? A tailored solution for just two may be more feasible than a generic solution for any number.

Answer (score 3):

With ***Microsoft 365*** you can try-

```
=UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,name1,name2)&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the quick response. Unfortunately this isn't working for me. Possibly because my named ranges are dynamic? Not sure...but I'm just getting an error when I replace `name1` and `name2` with my named ranges.

Comment: Dynamic shouldn't be problem. Can you try direct range instead of named range for troubleshooting purpose?

Comment: Another thing, if you are on Macbook then excel wouldn't support `FILTERXML()` function.

Comment: Ah, yes, I am on a Macbook.

Comment: Very clever to TEXTJOIN with a delimiter of `"</s><s>"`! Well done,