# Count of unique text values across multiple text ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data export that includes a list of teams with their members. It is around 100 teams with about 800 members.

Each member is in each team only once, but can be a member of multiple teams. I know roughly 200 of the members show up on more than 1 team. The data isn't complex, below is a dummy example.

| Team | Member |
| --- | --- |
| One | Dave |
| One | Martin |
| Two | Mary |
| Two | Frank |
| Two | Dave |

Each team is unique. Each member is unique. Each team can have 0 or more members, each member is on 1 or more teams.

Right now, I pull out the list of members in a team via a FILTER() function teams have backup teams, so I sometimes pull multiple lists of teams side by side.

What I can't figure out how to automate is a tally of the unique team members across all the teams I've pulled up. I can already count the membership of each team individually, but I can't get the syntax right to eliminate the overlap when someone is like Dave and in two or more teams.

Anyone able to give me a way to do this without a bunch of intermediary datasets?

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73901934/edit) to show us what you have tried?

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69861437/445425)

Comment: You need to describe to us, preferably with example output, what you want to happen when Dave appears in two teams.  Since you are using FILTER(), we know you have access to dynamic arrays, and that makes this super easy to solve once we find out what your desired logic is.