# Stacking two list of data on top of each other in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two excel sheets with one column each.

**Sheet1**

| A |
| --- |
| Fruits |
| Orange |
| Apple |
| Grapes |

**Sheet2**

| B |
| --- |
| Vegetables |
| Tomatoes |
| Potatoes |

Now, how do I use excel formula and populate on a third sheet stacking just the values

| A |
| --- |
| Orange |
| Apple |
| Grapes |
| Tomatoes |
| Potatoes |

Comment: Do you have Office 365 (HSTACK or VSTACK does exactly what you describe)

Comment: I am not able to use Vstack unfortunately

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69861437/445425) is a generalised Union function, for those that don't have VStack

Answer (score 1):

If your data has a header in `Sheet1!A1` and `Sheet2!A1` then in `Sheet3!A1` you could use (and drag down):

```
=IF(ROW()<=ROWS(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4),
           Sheet1!A2,
           SUBSTITUTE(
                         INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,
                         ROW()-ROWS(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4)+1),
                      "",""))
```

If the row number in the new sheet is smaller than or equal to the count of rows in the range of `Sheet1` then the result is `Sheet1!A2:A4` if the row is greater it'll index `Sheet2` column A and will get the result for in that range with the row that equals to the current row number minus the total count of rows of `Sheet1!A2:A4` + 1 to take the header into account.

In Office 365 a simple `=HSTACK(Sheet1!A2:A4,Sheet2!A2:A3)` would do.